# Django: ModelAdmin inside a template or view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

i am looking for to make a page or view of Model.Admin page inside my website, so users with right permission can access my custom model.admin page with all of its functions/actions.

im talking about this page:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCYIF.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.